# Black dots and low detail quality when baking my lowpoly model

Tags: texture-baking, baking

I am trying to bake a highpoly model to a lowpoly version I made with retopoflow but I'm getting strange UV issues.

**1.** I'm getting black dots around the edges of the model which shouldn't be there...

**2.** the quality of the lowpoly bake is very low and I can't seem to find a way to boost this, even though in the tutorials I am following, the detail is mostly kept even on very lowpoly frame models.

Would really appreciate some help everyone :)

[image: BlackSpots2]

[image: LowQual2]

Here are the settings and set up I've used to bake the model...

[image: Lighting_setup]
[image: Overlapping_model]
[image: Baking_Settings]

Comment: Sorry, not enough information is provided to track down the reason for the problems. How did you bake the image texture? Does the low-poly object fully cover the high-poly one? Have you increased the Extrusion value in bake settings? Have you tried a cage?

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I've added some screenshots of the settings I used to bake the model, I hope that helps give a clear picture. I did try a bunch of different settings for the raycast and extrusion but found I got the best results with 0.01 on both. I tried using a cage of both models but found no difference. also, it seems that the lowpoly model fully covers the highpoly.